# How do I import a file to my Ruby on Rails system without receiving the error "No file or directory sunch @ rb_sysopen - file.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-5

My program reads a .txt file for example, iterates over the internal information and stores it in the database.

But when the file is sent there is an error saying that it does not know the file path ... In my understanding, when the file was sent it was stored in the variable that is the source, but that's fine.

The error is visible in the attached image. It is noticed that a sharp line is exactly where the file that was not found will be opened.

But it is strange to say that he did not find the file if in the log he is able to capture the file and still pass the file name ... this can be important.

**Controller**

```
def import

  errors = []
  file = params['file']
  File.open(file).each do |line|
  begin
    line = line.split("\t")

    next if line[0] == "Comprador"

    buyer = line[0] rescue row[0]
    description = line[1] rescue line[1] 
    unity_price = line[2].to_f rescue line[2].to_f
    quantiti = line[3].to_i rescue line[3] .to_i
    address = line[4] rescue line[4] 
    provider = line[5] rescue line[5] 
    total_gross = "Total: #{(unity_price * quantiti).round(2)}"

    Record.create(buyer: buyer, description: description, unity_price: unity_price,  quantiti: quantiti,  address: address,  provider: provider)
  rescue Exception => err
    errors << err.message
  end
end

if errors.banck?
  flash[:success] = "Imported with successful"
else
  flash[:error] = errors.join(", ")
end
redirect_to "/file"
```

**View**

```
<%= form_tag import_path, method: :post do %>
 <div class="input-group no-border">
  <%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
  <%= button_tag 'submit'%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

the program hangs on the line "File.open (file) .each do | line |"

[image]

What should I do to stop receiving this error?

Comment: what is the value of `params['file']` in the error message?

Comment: the value is dados.txt

Comment: so if you know where the file is located, you can just add the path to the filename right?

Comment: I thought that passing the file as a parameter, the variable that receives the parameter would store the entire file, isn't that how it works?

Comment: I see, I used the File.realdirpath method to find the file path, but I got the same error, after all, as you said params is just a string and not the file itself

How can I pass the file in question based on the path? Could you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [file_field](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field) or [file_field_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-file_field_tag) in Rails you get an instance of [ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-open) in the parameters hash. This is basically just a wrapper around a tempfile instance.

You don't even need to use File.open in the first place and it causes the error since you're implicitly calling `#to_s` on the `UploadedFile` instance which just returns the base name of the file. If you want the path you would call `#to_path` but again - you don't need to.

You can open a UploadedFile instance by calling [#open](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-open) on it (duuh):

```
def import
  params[:file].open do |file|
    file.each do |line|
      # ...
    end
  end if params[:file]
end
```

But beyond that this code is really irrecoverably bad and littered with errors like `errors.banck?` as well as anti-patterns like inline rescue (rescue without a block or exception class which rescues *everything*) and `rescue Exception` which is a prime example of [Pokémon exception handling](https://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling). Handling exceptions does not mean bury everything.

Just start over from scratch and create a separate service object that takes a file as input and creates (and returns) instances of your model. Write tests that cover it. Then integrate it into your controller.

This also really smells like you're [reinventing the CSV wheel](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). Which you can do with something like:

```
require 'csv'

# Parses the file as CSV and imports the rows into the database
# Usage `MyImporterService.call(file)`
class MyImporterService
  attr_accessor :status, :errors, :results

  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
    @results = []
    @errors = []
  end

  def call
    CSV.new(@file, { col_sep: "\t" }).each do |row|
      begin
        @results << Record.create!(row.slice(:buyer, :description, :unity_price, :quantiti,  :address, :provider))
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
        @errors << e.message
      end
    end
    @results
  ensure 
    @file.close
  end

  # convenience method
  def self.call(file)
    new(file).tap do |instance|
      instance.call
    end
  end

  private

  def status
    if @results.any? && @errors.none?
      :imported_without_errors
    elsif @results.any?
      :imported_with_errors
    elsif @results.none?
      :nothing_imported
    end
  end

  def success?
    status == :imported_without_errors
  end 
end
```

```
def import
  unless params[:file].present?
    render :something and return # bail early
  end
  @import = MyImporterService.call(file)
  if @import.success?
    redirect to: 'somewhere', success: 'Import went without a hitch'
  else
    render :something # give the user feedback
  end
end
```

Comment: An error is returning where the "file" parameter in the "import" def @import variable is undefined for the object.

Comment: This isn't intended as a copy paste solution. I just don't know enough about your case to write anything like that. Its indented to show the general concepts involved and you'll need to do the actual handiwork.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but I realized that if I still wanted to use my code, just put the multipart attribute on the form and add the .path method to the parameters I receive. So it works, even with the mistakes you mentioned. Thank you!